# Lagrange multipliers for half-open constraints

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, machine-learning

The examples I see using Lagrange multipliers usually express a constraint as something like

$$x^2 + y^2 \ge C$$

but then solve the problem as if the constraint were

$$x^2 + y^2 = C$$

which works for many applications. But what if I'm not certain $L$ will be minimized on the constraint surface? Can Lagrange multipliers still be used?

The application is support vector machines where we minimize the 2-norm of a vector $\vec w$ subject to one constraint of the form

$$\vec w \cdot \vec x_i + b \ge 1$$

for many different vectors $\vec x_i$.

In this case, not all of the vectors will satisfy (and, indeed not all vectors *can* satisfy)

$$\vec w \cdot \vec x_i + b = 1$$

in the optimal solution.

If I create a Lagrangian like this:

$$L = \vec w \cdot \vec w - \lambda_i(1-\vec w \cdot \vec x_i + b)$$

then what's to stop $\lambda_i$ from going to $-\infty$ for those vectors for which

$$\vec w \cdot \vec x_i + b > 1 ?$$

Are Lagrange multipliers the right tool here?

Comment: For inequality constraints, use the KKT theorem.

Comment: That's it! h/t Misha!

Answer (score 1):

Define $L (x,y,\lambda)$ as $f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$. Where $f(x,y)$ is the function to be maximized, and $g(x,y)$ being the constraint.

Then,  $\text{max/min}\{f(x,y)\}$ subject to $g(x,y)\leq c$ happens at:

$$\frac {\partial L}{\partial x}=0,\frac {\partial L}{\partial y}=0, g(x,y)=c$$

But, in reality the last equation is just: $\lambda (g(x,y)-c)=0$

Furthermore, once you get those points, solve the equations and check which ones satisfy the the inequality $g(x,y)\leq c$. From there you can check the hessian matrix for the max and min.

You are on the right track, but the Lagrangian is the generalization you are looking for.

I hope that answered your question.

Comment: That seems to constrain the solution to the constraint boundary. One question to ask is how would the formulation change if the constraint were g(x,y) >= c?

Comment: @LeviBarnes langrangian will optimize the function, not only on the boundary, but the whole domain; however, you have to check which points are within the constraints,i.e., satisfy the inequality. That said, the formulation will not change for $g(x,y)\geq c$ you just have to check the points for the above said inequality!

Comment: @LeviBarnes I am sorry, I should have explained better: $L(x,y, \lambda)$ maximizez $f(x,y)$ on the whole domain, plus on the points $x,y$ such that $g(x,y)=c$. However, once you get the critical points check which ones satisfies $g(x,y)\ge c$, and disregard the others. From those points you can see which is max, which is min, etc. I hope that answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, let me state more fully the answer Misha alluded to in comments. Lagrange multipliers, should, for exactness, specify that $$\lambda \ge 0.$$

For these half-open constraints, Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions are appropriate. They impose conditions of "complementary slackness." For all constraints of the form
$$g_i(\vec x) \le 0$$
the KKT theorem dictates that 
$$\lambda_i g_i(\vec x) = 0.$$
These can be satisfied either by 
$$g_i(\vec x) = 0$$
or by 
$$\lambda_i = 0.$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Answer (score 0):

With that sort of constraint, we have two possibilities - either the maximum comes in the interior of the region, or it comes on the boundary.

If it comes in the interior, it's a "normal" optimization problem, in which we look for critical points where the gradient is zero. If it comes on the boundary, we look for critical points there with Lagrange multipliers. And since we don't know which it'll be in advance, we do both. An easy example to illustrate:

Example: Maximize $f(x,y)=xy$ on the unit disk $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2\le 1$

The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(x,y)=(y,x)$. This is zero at $(0,0)$, inside the disk. The value there is $0$. On the boundary $g(x,y)=1$, we look for places where $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla g=(2x,2y)$, solving the system $y=\lambda\cdot 2x$, $x=\lambda\cdot 2y$. Substituting the second equation in the first, $y=\lambda^2\cdot 4y$, and $\lambda=\pm\frac12$. The choice $\lambda=\frac12$ leads to two points $(\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ with $y=x$, and the choice $\lambda=-\frac12$ leads to two points $(\frac1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ with $y=-x$. The first pair give $f(x,y)=\frac12$, while the second pair give $f(x,y)=-\frac12$.

Out of all these critical points, the largest values are $\frac12$ at $(x,y)=(\frac1{\sqrt{2}},\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(x,y)=(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac1{\sqrt{2}})$, so that's the maximum.

But of course, we had to go through the full process, checking both the interior and the boundary. It's just like the one-dimensional case where a maximum can occur either in the interior or at an endpoint of the interval. In fact, we might need to go through several layers; if the constraints are something like a polyhedron, we have to check the interior, the faces, the edges, and the vertices all separately.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The issue is that we may have many constraints. At the optimum configuration, some will be satisfied at the constraint boundary and some in the interior. Unless we constrain $\lambda_i$ to be greater than or equal to zero, the Lagrangian will be minimized as $\lambda_i$ goes to $-\inf$ for any conditions satisfied in the interior.

Comment: With multiple inequality constraints, that leads to multiple faces, as in what I mentioned for the polyhedron.